# facebook.AppEventsLogger Got unexpected exception: java.lang.NullPointerException in android

Tags: android, facebook

I'm developing an Android app that should integrate with Facebook sdk v3.5.2I have gone through official guide and integrated the share dialog in my application. i have implemented everything correctly with the Facebook sdk when i try to share a link from my application to the facebook application .Iam getting an exception like.

D/com.facebook.AppEventsLogger(13656): Got unexpected exception: java.lang.NullPointerException.

also  i added the meta tag in manifest file

meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"

```
        android:value="@string/app_id"
```

please suggest a solution for this

Thanks
Rahul